# Some trouble autopath

Tags: 7, path-aliases, uri

I have some trouble with user path aliases. I want that every user has a small page under `/member/username`. To enforce that I build in the settings (`/admin/config/search/path/patterns`) under `user path` the plattern: `member/[user:name]`.

This seems to work fine but if I look at the contact link I get the link `/user/1/contact` I expect the link `http://example.com/member/username/contact`.

I have the same problem for some other links like editing any node. E.g. I have a link in my menu called *Updates* which is aviable under `/updates` but when I try to edit this one I see the url `/node/123/edit`.

I know that there is a module called `Extended Path Aliases` but this one breaks one of my own modules.

The problem there is that I use taxonomy to build paths for topics e.g. photography and sports. Normal posted news are then aviable under `/photography/a-great-day` or `/sports/scores` that will work with `Extended Path Aliases`, but it compleatly breaks my module with this pathes `sports/event/%date` (notation from menu_hook). That one seems to be routed to `/sports`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution via IRC. Simply install and activate [Sub-pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/subpathauto).